# Oracle: How to tell if center 3 characters are numbers?

Tags: oracle, parsing, regexp-like

I'm trying to separate the last character which should be a letter [A-F] if the the string has 3 numbers in a row somewhere previous.

For example,
103C would return 2 separate fields 103 and C
A103B would return 2 separate fields A103 and B.
FX103D would return 2 separate fields FX103 and D.
LOCATION2 would just return LOCATION2 and the 2nd field would be blank.

I've done something similar before with regexp_like, but I'm new to regex in general so I'm not sure how'd I'd accomplish this.

For a similar application, I've done regexp_like(c_lab.loc_code_from,'^\d{5}[[:alpha:]]') which looks at the first 5 characters, if they're numbers then the condition is satisfied and I split it up accordingly as shown below.

```
CASE
WHEN regexp_like(c_lab.loc_code_from,'^\d{5}[[:alpha:]]')
THEN substr(c_lab.loc_code_from, 1, 5)
ELSE c_lab.loc_code_from
END as "From Location",
CASE
WHEN regexp_like(c_lab.loc_code_from,'^\d{5}[[:alpha:]]')
THEN substr(c_lab.loc_code_from,6,1)
ELSE 'A'
END as "From Level ID"
```

Answer (score 1):

YOu can use the below which is as per your requirement . [The Db fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/GnGUTokC)

```
         WITH data
         AS (SELECT 'A103B' dt
             FROM   dual
             UNION
             SELECT '103C'
             FROM   dual
             UNION
             SELECT 'FX104D'
             FROM   dual
             UNION
             SELECT 'Location2'
             FROM   dual)
    SELECT Nvl(Substr(dt, 1, Instr(dt, Regexp_substr ( dt, '[[:digit:]]{3}' ))
                             + 2), dt),
           Substr(dt, Instr(dt, Regexp_substr ( dt, '[[:digit:]]{3}' ))
                      + 3)
    FROM   data;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution which takes advantage of knowing that REGEXP_REPLACE() returns the original string if the pattern is not found (FYI - REGEXP_SUBSTR() returns NULL if the pattern is not found).

Part_1 is that match of everything up to but not including the last capital letter.  Part_2 is the capital letter at the end of the string.

```
WITH tbl(str) AS (
  SELECT '103C' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A103B' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'FX103D' FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'LOCATION2' FROM dual
)
SELECT str,
       REGEXP_REPLACE(str, '(.*\d{3})[A-Z]$', '\1') AS part_1,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(str, '.*\d{3}([A-Z]$)', 1, 1, NULL, 1) AS part_2
from tbl;


STR        PART_1     PART_2   
---------- ---------- ---------
103C       103        C        
A103B      A103       B        
FX103D     FX103      D        
LOCATION2  LOCATION2           

4 rows selected.
```

EDIT to answer question in the comment.  Wrap the call to REGEXP_SUBSTR() in a call to NVL():

```
NVL(REGEXP_SUBSTR(str, '.*\d{3}([A-Z]$)', 1, 1, NULL, 1), 'A') AS part_2
```

Comment: This worked great! Thanks you. If I wanted to replace the NULL with a 'A', how could I go about that? Simply replacing the NULL with a 'A' doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT value,
       REGEXP_REPLACE(value, '^(.*\d{3}.*)([A-F])$', '\1') AS part1,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(value, '^(.*\d{3}.*)([A-F])$', 1, 1, NULL, 2) AS part2
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (value) AS
  SELECT 'A103B'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '103C'      FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'FX104D'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Location2' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| VALUE | PART1 | PART2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A103B | A103 | B |
| 103C | 103 | C |
| FX104D | FX104 | D |
| Location2 | Location2 | *null* |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/vK8HysJL)